# php mvc dynamic sitemap

Tags: php, .htaccess

hello i am using php mvc model. I created a sitemap. Path: localhost / sitemap
Whatever I did in .htaccess, I could not convert sitemap.xml. I could not solve the problem.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType text/javascript js mjs
</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)$ index.php [QSA]

#Sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [NC,L]
```

index.php

```
$routeExplode = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$route = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', $routeExplode[0])));

require controller(route(0));
```

init.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

    // Define an array of directories in the order of their priority to iterate through.
    $dirs = array(
        __DIR__ . '/classes/', // Core classes example
    );

    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        if (file_exists($dir . strtolower($class_name) . '.php')) {
            require_once($dir . strtolower($class_name) . '.php');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably configured it as * .php from the controls, so the change in index.php solves your problem.

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap [L]
```

index

```
if (route(0) === "sitemap.xml") {
    require_once '....';
}
```